# Desktop translation tool

Tags: translation

I am a journalist whose primary job is to translate articles from Russian to English language. Basically what I need is something that watches clipboard too & (via a click or something)auto translate them to some pre-set language (in my case Russian » English).

Comment: There's a google-translate for desktop that is java powered, but it requires a google-api key.  Just something worth thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

This project looks interesting - try Dual Clip Translator: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcliptranslator/

It's "powered by Google", so I bet it will do Russian to English.

The only downside to this program is that there are no DEB's or RPM's. Look for some documentation to find out how to use it. My suspicion is that Linux users must compile from source.

Comment: Well it looks interesting under windows not linux, no GUI here :(

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you use translate.google.com for the translation? You can also install "Auto-Translate" extension for Google Chrome if you want to translate selected text in the browser: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-translate/obgoiaeapddkeekbocomnjlckbbfapmk

And why Fedora in Ubuntu forums? :)

Comment: Because there  is an official fedora tag here

Answer (score 1):

Ther's an Ubuntu based distribution called [tuxtrans](https://www.uibk.ac.at/tuxtrans/) especially designed for translators.  If you don't want to install a new distro and multi-boot, other options include running a VM, Booting the ISO live, and if you want to roll your own a look at [the included software](https://www.uibk.ac.at/tuxtrans/software.html) and [a bit of research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer-assisted_translation_software_for_Linux) should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

While working with multilanguage [gitbooks](https://www.gitbook.com/) for a while I came across this [Google Translate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benshabatnoam.google-translate-ext) extension for [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/).
When I select some text in the editor and hit the shortcut keys the selected text is translated into the target language. Any language! That easy!