# Quick translation when reading text

Tags: software-recommendation, dictionary, translation

I need a fast translator for Ubuntu; in fact, I want a software that translates after a double click on the text or after copying it to the clipboard, like the Google Translate Android app. What advice do you have?

Comment: There are a vast variety of translation tools available for Linux. Can you narrow down your requirements a bit?

Comment: Well, thank you @Eldin ,
In fact, I want a software that translates after a double click on the text or after copying it to the clipboard ... like google translate Android App .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Desktop translation tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232170/destop-translation-tool)

Answer (score 0):

The google translator can translate a document. Can help you.

[Google Translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B2Gv.png)

Comment: Ok , it's good , But sometimes i need translate just any word in a document not all the document And also want to using that in ubuntu not in browser

Comment: @smr If you [edit] your post to include your requirements you might get an answer that you like. Cheers!